# How to make a global class for custom background color in flutter

Tags: flutter, class, colors, background, background-color

I have a LinearBackground color like this

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue])));
```

In my case, I have 3 screens and I would like to apply my custom background to all of my screens that I have, is there a way to declare my above code to become one class so that I can call it to my screen whenever I need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dart file with class just like this

```
class AppConstants {

  static const BoxDecoration myBoxDecoration = BoxDecoration(
  gradient: LinearGradient(
  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
  colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue]));

}
```

and use it like this

```
child: Container(decoration: AppConstants.myBoxDecoration),
```